# How to reset the service reminder on a 2002 Mercedes-Benz CLK 200 Kompressor?

Tags: maintenance, scheduled-maintenance, mercedes-benz, service

I have been looking for a few days now on how to reset the service reminder that keeps showing every time I start the car. I know the car repair shop can do this, but I would like to know how to do it myself, since most of the service can be done by myself or friends, and I do not want to pay a loads of money just to get rid of an "on screen reminder". :)

So does anyone know how to reset the service reminder on a 2002 Mercedes-Benz CLK 200 Kompressor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found out how to reset the service reminder manually. It was easier than expected.

**Here it comes in steps:**

1. Put in key
2. Turn key to position 2 *(this might be tricky, there
   are 3 positions, but its actually just before the engine starts, all
   electronics are on, lights flashing on "dashboard")*
3. Use buttons on steering wheel to navigate to "Service Reminder".
4. Press and hold the R button for 2-3 seconds.
5. Confirm by pressing R again.

Comment: How / where did you find out?

Comment: Owners manual. That seems like a good source. :-) Tested and confirmed!